# Raspberry Pi Node-RED Touch input

Tags: raspberry-pi, touch, node-red, touchscreen

I have a smart home (node-red) with a Raspberry Pi and a official 7" touchscreen as dashboard.

I now want to turn off the backlight after a certain time and I know how to do that. I also want to turn it back on if I touch the screen at any place. 
I have no idea how to do that, as there is no node-red node for touch input or something like that.

Anyone did this before?

Comment: I am not sure if the solution should come from node-red.  I have also no experience with touchscreen connected to raspberry pi. ... Is the issue related to https://forums.pimoroni.com/t/touch-screen-wake-up/3589/7    ... if you don't get much response here, you might also considering posting it in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/